# Connection speed switches automatically from 1 Gbps to 100 Mbps

Tags: networking, ethernet, connection, internet-connection, speed

So I have an intenet connection that lets me use 600Mbs initially when I plug in my ethernet cable I can see 1 Gbps connection speed (in ethernet status window).
The issue is that I can see that every now and then 5-10 min I see duration reset (in ethernet status window) and usually on the first reset (some times on the second one) speed switches to 100Mbps and now I have max speed of 10MBs for the love of god I dug through google left and right, can some one lend me a hand on this one?

**Operating sysytem:** Win 10

**One more addition** - I believe that if start downloading something (eg. using speed to its fullest potential after unplugging and plugging it back in) - speed remains constant. Maybe it is some kind of bad power saving thing?

**Why I think that the cable is not an issue:**
Since I can get my desired speed and keep it while I download something I believe this is not a cable issue. - connection speed faints if I don't stress it.

**I think we can be sure that this is not the modem issue** I have just literally connected cable straight to the thingie that takes in optical cable and converts light signal to electrical one.. to my surprise 100Mbps connection

**At this point I am thinking it could be my ethernet adapter** my motherboard has Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

Comment: Link speed dropping might be a reaction on transmission errors. Just where you find that depends on the OS. Could you add which OS you are using.

Comment: You may want to check your Ethernet cable and make sure it's at least Cat 5e (not just 5), and/or try a different cable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this gonna be helpful !

As far as I am concerned, you should first consider the driver issue cause an old versioned NIC may have impact on this, if it is the problem maybe you should upgrade it.

Note that you say that the cable is not an issue, you'd better use a cable tester app in the BIOS, if it comes back with errors on the cable, your NIC might be physically damaged in a way that is preventing 1Gbps negotiation.

Hope this might help!